# Why is this F# sequence expression cubic time instead of linear?

Tags: algorithm, debugging, f#, time-complexity, sequence

I stumbled upon a strange time complexity behaviour when using `Seq.unfold`. Here's the minimal case I could come up with to reproduce this.

```
let idUnfolder sequence =
   sequence
   |> Seq.tryHead
   |> Option.map (fun head -> (head, Seq.tail sequence))

let seqIdWithUnfold sequence =
   Seq.unfold idUnfolder sequence
```

The function `seqIdWithUnfold` returns the given sequence itself. I would expect the resulting sequence to be iterated in linear time as `Seq.unfold` is O(n), `Seq.tryHead` and `Seq.tail` are O(1) (correct me if I'm wrong). However, against all my knowledge, it has a cubic complexity.

I tested the execution time with the following function with a set of `n` values.

```
let test n =
   let start = System.DateTime.Now
   Seq.init n id
   |> seqIdWithUnfold
   |> Seq.iter ignore
   let duration = System.DateTime.Now - start
   printfn "%f" duration.TotalSeconds
```

What makes this operation cubic in complexity?

Comment: A `seq` is essentially an IEnumerable. This means that any operation on it has to iterate it again, which in turn means executing the generator/iterator function again. `Seq.init` or `Enumerable.Range` are used to produce an `IEnumerable<>` without actually taking up any RAM, which means they have to loop and generate values on the fly, an `O(N)` operation. I suspect if you use an array or list of N items you'll get better performance.

Comment: BTW since a Seq is an IEnumerable<T>, you can pass any container to functions that expect an IEnumerabl<T>. *Some* operations will actually check to see whether they work against a list or array (ie containers implementing `IList`) and optimize their code - instead of walking to the i-th element, they'll return i-th element itself. With linked lists, the `.tail` operation only needs to return the second element, instead of iterating the entire sequence to produce the tail. *Maybe* that's optimized too

Comment: `Seq.tail` is O(n) - https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1374-L1380

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`seq` is almost always `O(n)`.
A `seq` aka `IEnumerable<T>` is essentially:

```
type Enumerator<'a> = {
    getNext : unit -> 'a option
}

type Seq<'a> = {
    getEnumerator: unit -> Enumerator<'a>
}
```

Every time you evaluate a sequence, a new `Enumerator` is created which captures the state of enumeration. `getNext` is then repeatedly called till the sequence terminates.

You can see this for yourself, if you replace a `seq` at any point with with

```
source |> Seq.map(fun x -> printfn "Eval %A" x; x)
```

Let's show the calls to `getEnumerator` as well:

```
let sq  = 
    seq {  
        let mutable ctr = 0
        do printfn "Init  _" 
        while true do
            ctr <- ctr + 1
            printfn "Yield %d" ctr
            yield ctr
        }     

seqIdWithUnfold (sq |> Seq.take 3) |> Seq.toList |> printfn "%A"
```

And there's the output:

```
Init  _
Yield 1
Init  _
Yield 1
Yield 2
Init  _
Yield 1
Yield 2
Yield 3
Init  _
Yield 1
Yield 2
Yield 3
[1; 2; 3]
```

This shows you the classic `n(n+1)/2` pattern.

You can see that complexity will have *n + n<sup>2</sup>* terms in it.

If can use list, you'll get `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`.

If you really want `O(1)`, use Arrays.

Comment: I see, so when iterating over the `seqIdWithUnfold`, evaluating `Seq.tryHead` for the nth time requires evaluation of the tail of the tail of the tail of.. (n times) the initial sequence, hence the n^2 complexity. I wonder if there is a better workaround than using the mutable ´Enumerator´ as `Seq.unfold` `'State` (using lists or arrays in my use case is not acceptable). And I still wonder how I measured n^3.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do? Your current example returns the sequence itself, which is pointless, so I'm assuming there must be a bigger problem you're trying to solve with this. In order to answer whether there is a "better workaround", we'd need to know what it would be for.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin is right. I assumed that he'd use a mapping other than id in his implementation. Perhaps you could ask another question?

Comment: @jaakkoc There's the cost of constructing the *n* enumerators, which is usually amortized over longer sequences. This could make it seem like n^3 in timing tests for short sequences.

Comment: My final solution was to convert Seq into FSharpx.Collections.LazyList. I have many functions which require passing the tail of a sequence through recursions.

Answer (score 0):

As Philip Carter mentioned in the comments `Seq.tail` is O(n).

I'm not sure why an F# List would be unacceptable, F# Lists are singly linked lists so you can get the constant time tail. If you need to accept any sequence as your signature just convert to a List before unfolding, it still makes it O(n), This example you presented can't be lazy anyway unless you really didn't need the tail.

```
let seqIdWithUnfold sequence =
       sequence
           |> Seq.toList
           |> List.unfold idUnfolder 
           |> List.toSeq
```

Your processing example still works with the List module

```
 let idUnfolder listSeq =
        listSeq
        |> List.tryHead
        |> Option.map (fun head -> (head, List.tail listSeq))
```

But I think it would look a bit cleaner as

```
let idUnfolder =
    function | [] -> None
             | h::t -> Some(h, t);
```

Benchamarks

```
|          Method |        Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|---------------- |------------:|----------:|----------:|
|        Original | 4,683.88 us | 36.462 us | 34.106 us |
|  ListConversion |    15.63 us |  0.202 us |  0.179 us |

// * Hints *
Outliers
  Benchmarkem.ListConversion: Default -> 1 outlier  was  removed (16.53 us)

// * Legends *
  Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
  Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
  StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
  1 us   : 1 Microsecond (0.000001 sec)
```

Comment: `Seq.tail` is O(1), enumerating over it is O(n). Lists are unacceptable when dealing with very long, even endless sequences.

Comment: @jaakkoc, I see , because `Seq.tail` is lazy, and your only planing on taking the first element your saying it should be O(1), however since `Seq.tail` wraps your enumerable with an enumerable that skips one, and each unfold iteration you are wrapping with another that skips one. So each unfold where it's trying to get head it's iterating from the the start of the original seq (and also growing in memory). If you don't care about the tail and are not wanting to deal with all elements then you should simply use a `seq { (*loop yield*) }`.